# How to test MatSort with Jasmine

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine

I've been trying to figure out how to correctly test my table (uses mat-table) with MatSort. Sorting my table works fine with ng serve and I've been able to click the sorting button for one of the columns but I do not see a change in the table after I click on the button in my test. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated!

snippet of table.component.ts

```
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';

export class tablecomponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
 @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit(){
this.source = new MatTableDataSource(this.list);
this.source.sort = this.sort;
}
}
```

snippet of table.component.html

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="source">
<ng-container matColumnDef="column_a"
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>column a</th>
<td mat-cell></td>
</table>
```

snippet of table-component.spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MatTableModule, MatTableDataSource, MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { tableComponent } from './table.component';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar'; 
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatSortModule, MatSortHeader, Sort, MatSort, SortDirection, MatSortHeaderIntl } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';

describe('CtableComponent', () => {
  let component: tableComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<tableComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ tableComponent],
      imports : [
        MatTableModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatSortModule,
        CdkTableModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(tableComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

it('should show a sorted table', async(() => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const table = compiled.querySelector('table');
    const button = compiled.querySelectorAll('button.mat-sort-header-button');
    component.list = TABLE_TEST_DATA.list;
    component.source = new MatTableDataSource<Con>(component.list);
    component.sort = new MatSort();
    component.source.sort = component.sort;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    button[0].click();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
it('should show a sorted table', async(() => {
    // no need to call ngOnInit, the last fixture.detectChanges(); will call ngOnInit for us
    // component.ngOnInit();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    const table = compiled.querySelector('table');
    const button = compiled.querySelectorAll('button.mat-sort-header-button');
    component.list = TABLE_TEST_DATA.list;
    component.source = new MatTableDataSource<Con>(component.list);
    component.sort = new MatSort();
    component.source.sort = component.sort;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    button[0].click();
    // after click on the first element, detect the changes to ensure sorting took place
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // your assertions, i.e. expect to see the first element being sorted in the table
}));
```

Comment: I added a ```       expect(table.rows[1].cells[0].textContent).toBe("test");
``` after the button click() and made the above changes ^. But the component.source after the click is still the same with no sorted changes

Comment: For the `table.rows[1].cells[0].textContent`, make sure to grab a new reference because the order changed after sorting with the button click. Are you sure that `button.mat-sort-header-button` when clicked will do the sorting? When running the application, select this element with the developer tools, in the console type `$0.click()` and see it doing the sort. If it doesn't do the sorting, another element has the click listener.

Comment: For me the button in the header was not a real button but a div with `role='button'`, so this actually worked: `const button = compiled.querySelectorAll(div.mat-sort-header-container)`, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role